# Usage of the word dawn

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, american-english

Following are some of the sentences which I framed using the word `dawn`
Not sure if it is a proper way to use it.

1. I was trying to understand it for a long time and today it dawned
2. I am reading the material, but it will take some time so that it dawns on me.
3. The subject needs to dawn on me

Are these correct usage of the word `dawn`? I am using it which means: `understanding`

Answer (score 5):

"Dawn" (or "dawn on") doesn't mean "understanding," but rather "the *beginning* of understanding." It is similar in meaning to "epiphany" or "revelation." It is a metaphor for the moment the sun rises above the horizon and the light shines on your face.

1. I was trying to understand it for a long time and today it **dawned on me: it is all about the cats**. (I suddenly realized that cats were the key to understanding.)
2. Doesn't really work with this usage. Better to simply say "until I get it" or "until I understand the material."
3. Doesn't work. Try: "I don't get it." or "I am struggling to understand."